# How many subgroups here?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a group with order 24, it has 8 elements with order 3, then how many subgroups does it have?

I try to write 24=$2^3*3$, and it has subgroups with order 1,2,4,8, but I don't know what to do with the elements with order 8.

Comment: There are no groups with exactly $3$ elements of order $8$.  If $g$ has order $8$, then $g^3,g^5,g^7$ also have order $8$.

Comment: You should be able to see that there are three subgroups of order 8.